# multi columns not working in ie 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, multiple-columns

Here's the code in my html:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactme.html">Contact Me</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And here's my css:

```
nav {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 1px;
    -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1px;
    -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #000;    
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 1px;
    column-rule: 1px solid #000;
}
nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
}
```

When I view this in IE 11 and resize the window to tablet size (between 481px and 768px) the navigation gets all wonky, but works fine in Firefox and Chrome.  You can see the page in action at:

http://gc.palomar.edu/33605/33605jknowles5799/index.html

I've looked online everywhere and this should work for IE 11 as IE 11 supports multi columns, but it's not.  I've tried using the IE developer tools to add/remove stuff to try and figure out what's going on, but I'm still not seeing it.

Help please!
Julie

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Setting the style `overflow: hidden;` on the `li` tags seems to resolve this issue.

Comment: I had a similar issue where I had a bunch of divs running across three columns and the top part of some of the divs was being displayed at the end of the preceding column. Very odd. Adding ``overflow: hidden;`` to each ``div`` did the trick. Worked first time.

Comment: I had a similar problem with IE11 and a multi column list of Divs. `overflow:hidden` worked well in this case, too. Thanks.

Comment: I have not been able to get overflow: hidden to work yet... I have also seen the issue @ColinJamesFirth refers to and for drop shadows I had to make sure the element shadows weren't too big and that the padding was enough to keep them from crossing between the columns.